# How to incorporate a textarea into a Jquery dialog

Tags: jquery-ui, textarea, modal-dialog

I am attempting to insert a textarea into a JQuery dialog and I am getting hung up on the syntax of how the dialog I have to work with is set up (I didn't write the dialog by the way, I just want to make changes to it). I have looked at some of the other questions that are similar to this on this site but they don't seem to answer my question so I am hoping someone can shed some light on this for me.

Here is the code:

```
$('.rejection_toggle').button().click(function(event) {
 var $dialog = $('<div />', {
   text: Drupal.t('Are you sure you want to reject this form? If so, then please leave a comment as to why you are rejecting it.')
    })
 var $button = $(this);
 $('body').append($dialog);
 $dialog.dialog({
  title: Drupal.t('Reject this form?'),
  buttons: {
      'Reject': function (event) {
        var $submitID = $button.attr('id').replace('rejection-toggle', 'approval-buttons-reject'),
        $submitButton = $('#' + $submitID);

        $submitButton.click();
        $dialog.dialog('close');
      },
      'Cancel': function (event) {
        $dialog.dialog('close');
      }
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

So how would I go about inserting a textarea before the buttons?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. I need to add:

```
var textArea = $('<textarea style="width:100%" />'); 
$dialog.append(textArea);
```

After the var $dialog line.

Now I need to figure out how to get the input back into Drupal.